# How to implements the method getRSASignerCredentials() for DefaultTlsServer with BouncyCastle

Tags: java, ssl, bouncycastle, dtls

My current Java code with library `bctls-jdk18on-1.72.jar` for an implementation of `TlsServer` look like:

```
class DefaultTlsServerImpl extends DefaultTlsServer {
    ...
    @Override
    protected TlsCredentialedSigner getRSASignerCredentials() throws IOException {
        TlsCryptoParameters cryptoParams = new TlsCryptoParameters(context);
        SignatureAndHashAlgorithm signatureAndHashAlgorithm = null;
        if (TlsUtils.isSignatureAlgorithmsExtensionAllowed(context.getServerVersion())) {
            signatureAndHashAlgorithm = new SignatureAndHashAlgorithm(HashAlgorithm.sha256, SignatureAlgorithm.rsa);
        }
        return new BcDefaultTlsCredentialedSigner(cryptoParams, BC_TLS_CRYPTO, PRIVATE_KEY, CERTIFICATE, signatureAndHashAlgorithm);
    }
    ...
```

}

I receive the follow exception after the method `getRSASignerCredentials()`was called:

```
org.bouncycastle.tls.TlsFatalAlert: internal_error(80)
    at org.bouncycastle.tls.DTLSServerProtocol.accept(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.tls.DTLSServerProtocol.accept(Unknown Source)
    ...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid algorithm: {sha256(4),rsa(1)}
    at org.bouncycastle.tls.crypto.impl.bc.BcTlsDSSSigner.generateRawSignature(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.tls.DefaultTlsCredentialedSigner.generateRawSignature(DefaultTlsCredentialedSigner.java:53)
    at org.bouncycastle.tls.TlsUtils.generateServerKeyExchangeSignature(TlsUtils.java:2602)
    at org.bouncycastle.tls.TlsECDHEKeyExchange.generateServerKeyExchange(TlsECDHEKeyExchange.java:79)
    at org.bouncycastle.tls.DTLSServerProtocol.serverHandshake(Unknown Source)
    ... 16 more
```

That I think the mistake is there. How can I implements correctly the method `getRSASignerCredentials()`?

PS: If I try:

```
new SignatureAndHashAlgorithm( HashAlgorithm.sha256, SignatureAlgorithm.ecdsa );
```

because this is related to the certificate `SHA256withECDSA` then I receive `org.bouncycastle.tls.TlsFatalAlert: illegal_parameter(47)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception is saying you're providing a DSA or ECDSA certificate, but it can't use those with the RSA SignatureAlgorithm or with `getRSASignerCredentials()`.

Generate a RSA certificate and try again. Or keep your ECDSA certificate and instead override `getECDsaSignerCredentials()` and try again.

Comment: Or implement getECDSA to return the ECDSA cert and key _and_ a sigalg for ECDSA, _and_ alter the ciphersuite list so that an ECDSA-authenticated suite gets chosen not an RSA-authenthenticated one.